# Mac is heating up, how to resolve?

Tags: mac

[image]I am using MacBook Air . Few hours ago I removed iTunes, iMovies, Books and avast. I have noticed that after removal of the apps, when I switch it on it gets heated up after running for sometime. Is it due to removal of the preinstalled apps or some other reasons ? Can anybody suggest me a probable solution ?

Comment: Which applications did you remove and how? Does Activity Monitor show any processes using a lot of CPU (and if yes, please add a screenshot)?

Comment: I removed iTunes, iMovies, Books apps.@nohillside

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of my activity monitor@nohillside

Comment: I thought it is an opendirectoryd issue. Then following online(https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201149) available solutions I checked directory utility. But the search path "/Active Directory/EXAMPLE.COM” and "/Active Directory/EXAMPLE.COM/All Domains” is not there. Then I found that it may be due to broken symlinks (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7462229) but I dont know how to find them.

Comment: I also uninstalled avast and the message below is being show in system.log continuously:                                            Aug 14 17:36:36 HIRAKJYOTIs-Air com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.avast.uninstall): Service only ran for 4 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 6 seconds. I dont know what does this mean.

Comment: Might be time for a reboot, just to cleanout any stuck processes etc.

Comment: I uninstalled avast yesterday, but I can still see in the /tmp folder the log files appearing. Is that a probable cause ? How to stop them appearing ?

Comment: How did you deinstall Avast and did you reboot since? Right now the problems you describe are all over the place and most probably not related to the removal of iTunes, getting answers will be difficult.

Comment: I uninstalled avast by " sudo rm -rf /Applications/Avast.app". Yes I restarted the computer many times.

Comment: I'm sure Avast comes with a uninstaller which also removes any LaunchDaemons etc (which still hang around so get the errors in the logs)

Comment: I have already removed avast and I dont have any uninstaller now with me. Am I right ? What else can I do ?

Comment: Reinstall Avast and uninstall properly? Search the internet for instructions about "how to manually deinstall Avast on macOS"?

Comment: I tried reinstalling but it shows :Avast is already installed, please uninstall the previous version first.

Comment: Avast should have a support site for this

Comment: Yes, they have. I have been able to uninstall the remnants. This article helped me: https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=231437.0. But let me wait a few minutes so that I can really be confirmed about heating issue.

Comment: Yes , the heating problem has been resolved. Thank you@nohillside

Comment: Nothing in here shows a heating issue.  Why exactly did you remove iTunes, iMoveies, etc.?  [Removing pre-installed apps isn't a good idea](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/399224/119271)